# navigator.app.exitApp() well working on intel xdk preview but not working as an apk file

Tags: android, cordova, apk, intel, mobile-application

I have an Intel XDK project. I want to use

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

in a condition.

Code is OK and well working on XDK preview and debugger mode. But after build the apk file, exitapp is not working.

Because it's working in debugger mode, I cannot control the problem.

As an idea: Maybe Intel XDK (preview apk) have a special plugin to run exitapp function and this plugin may not in my package. I search it but i just faced cordova.custom.plugins.exitapp. I added this but still not working.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I added cordova.js with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

but my html file is in a directory. I changed the adding row with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
```

and it's working.

Intel XDK insert cordova.js itselft. So I did not see cordova.js and reason of fail is this situation. Just tried and found.